# SAS: how to plot boxplots for each quantitative var in few lines of code

Tags: sas, boxplot

I have one qualitative variable ("Group") and 38 quantitative variables ( some chemical elements: Al, Mg, K, Cu...): I would like to plot a boxplot for each of those quantitative vars against the qualitative one (eg. y-axis = Al, x-axis = Group) but in a single (or few) lines of codes, instead of typing this

```
 proc boxplot data= Dataana.Pot;
plot Al*Group;
run;
```

38 times with a different elements.

How could I do this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTM

```
PLOT (analysis-variables)*group-variable <(block-variables )> <=symbol-variable> </ options > ;
```

Comment: It is obvious.
PLOT (list of 38 analysis variables)*group;